# Slide out menu Bootstrap4 appearing on top of main page

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a pop-out menu with bootstrap 4 and jquery.

I have been following this tutorial here: https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index3.html

And right now mine looks like this...

[image]

Not sure what's causing this behavior. I originally thought it was `<div class="wrapper">` being in the wrong place. I originally had it on the outside of the body tag and it wasn't working. I moved it into the body like the source code of the example and that didn't seem to change anything..

YOu can see my source code here: https://www.seekadventure.net/adventureMap2.html

Comment: What you are asking is to compare the demo code with your code and hope we see the difference. Always willing to help out, but SO is not a debugging service. Please post a [reprex].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your css file-
and  i think solw your problem

```
#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -250px;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #ffc107;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    padding: 1em;
}
#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
}
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    top: 0;
}
```